# How to select the whole variable name including $ in Visual Studio Code in PHP?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I am using the latest version of Visual Studio Code and I am using the PHP programming language.  I am selecting a variable but it only selects the variable name, not the *$* symbol.

**By default it selects like this:**

[image: Selection of variable name without dollar sign]

**But I want it like this:**

[image: Selection of variable name with dollar sign]

Is there any setting that enables this behavior?

Any information on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know, but seems selecting the name is the most intuitive because you find yourself renaming things quickly. Is selecting and then using shift + left arrow not good enough?

Comment: Select and shift + left not working as well as it is not selecting whole string though, you can try it.

Comment: I also found that VS code is not good for PHP that is good for only node and typescript , It is not properly giving me a suggestion like PHP strome does.

Comment: Visual Studio Code relies on extensions for most language features. It comes with some extensions already installed but for PHP you need to install them yourself. I can suggest PHP Intelephense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode - Is there a way to customise double-click select behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34781471/vscode-is-there-a-way-to-customise-double-click-select-behaviour)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You need to remove the `$` symbol from the [`editor.wordSeparators` directive](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings). This is the default value:

```
// Characters that will be used as word separators when doing word related navigations or operations.
"editor.wordSeparators": "`~!@#$%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?",
```

You can make this [language specific](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_languagespecific-editor-settings) if you want, so it only applies to PHP.

Comment: context helps.
this way is also global to all languages, which may not be desired or compatible with other languages.

Answer (score 108):

The best way is to edit the VsCode settings.json and specify it for the PHP language.
You can open it typing VsCode command:

> Preferences: open settings (JSON)

And specify inside the "editor.wordSeparators" setting for your language removing the '$' symbol:

```
"[php]": {
  "editor.wordSeparators": "`~!@#%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Adding your 3 lines of JSON code (plus a comma) to the `settings.json` file that I found by following the example at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations worked.

Comment: The diff compared to the default: $ has been removed, \ has been escaped once more, and " has been escaped.

Comment: @ahnbizcad it looks like the diff is only that the $ has been removed. I checked my default value and it looks like this: `\`~!@#$%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?` It already has escaped backslash and escaped double quote

Answer (score 11):

This solution **works for every programming language** over Visual Studio Code. You can do it in a simple way:

On Windows:
***File > preferences > Settings***

On macOS: ***Code > preferences > Settings***

Find: **Extensions -> PHP**

Click over: **Edit in settings.json**

[image]

*in file `settings.json`*, add the new setting line:

```
"editor.wordSeparators": "`~!@#%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?"
```

If you need it **just for PHP**, forget about the other line, and add only this one:

```
"[php]": {
    "editor.wordSeparators": "`~!@#%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?"
}
```

Remember this settings file is JSON formatted, so don’t forget to add a "comma" before adding a new line (in case you have multiple line settings).

Otherwise if you have your settings empty (not probably), enclose this settings over brackets:

```
{
    //enter each line setting here
}
```

Comment: you're right thats the best solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the below `code` in `file > preferences > Settings > settings.json`

```
"editor.wordSeparators": "`~!@#%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?",
```

Comment: Don't you see it's already been answered that way one million times?