# Why in visual studio code by double clicking on the variable $ is not selected?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In visual studio code  1.54.1 I found that double clicking on php variable
literal of the var is selected, but not first $ char, that seems not good.

I found branch:
[VSCode - Is there a way to customise double-click select behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34781471/vscode-is-there-a-way-to-customise-double-click-select-behaviour/43785391)

and set rule

```
"editor.wordSeparators": "`~!@#$%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?"
```

and looks like with this rule variable is selected with : https://prnt.sc/10mc93s but when I want to copy this vraible and to paste in this editor first $ char : https://prnt.sc/10mcdhd Can it be some other rule for copy paste operations? If to paste this var in other editor - first $ char is lost too...

Thanks!

Comment: if you select the variable and $ with the keyboard (Shift+Arrow) and copy-paste the $ is part of the paste? if yes there is a problem with the display of selected text

Comment: Shift+Arrow - which command do you mean ? I found similar command "editor.action.insertCursorBelow"? Checking it I see first "$" is lost when making copy/paste in the same window

Comment: have you never selected text by using the keyboard? Find this keybinding to get the command.

Comment: because `$` is not a valid identifier char in most languages

Comment: But '$' char is in  wordSeparators above? Can it be that I need to modify this expression ?

Comment: the fact that it is in the wordSeparators means: **it is not a word character** ==> do not include it in the dbl-click-word-selection

Comment: I see your point. Is this option configurable? VC developers could not forget about php features...

Comment: Yes, just remove `$` from that word separators setting.  If you want, you can make that language-specific to php files.

Comment: Looks like that  does not work. Are there some other relative options ?